# Assembly.LoadFrom {"Illegal characters in path."} error

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

I have the following declaration:

```
Assembly SampleAssembly;
SampleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("\bin\mycppapp.dll");
```

where the bin folder is inside an ASP.NET MVC 5 project structure and it contains the mycppapp.dll file, which is a Visual C++ entity with various methods. When the code processes this line, I see in the debugger the following error:

> {"Illegal characters in path."}

What can I do to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: This should be updated to include the `c++-cli` tag. And possibly remove the `c++` tag.

Comment: @RawN edit completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, C++ and C#, the backslash (`\`) is an escape character. For example, `\r` signifies a carriage return and `\n` signifies a line feed.

Use two backslashes to insert a single one.

```
Assembly SampleAssembly;
SampleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("\\bin\\mycppapp.dll");
```